# What is the difference between SimpleTestCase.settings() and django.test.override_settings?

Tags: django, unit-testing

Django provides different ways to change settings([documentations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/tools/#overriding-settings)) in a test in different levels (TestCase class, test method, context manager). I understand the difference between `override_settings` and `modify_settings`, but I can't get the difference between `SimpleTestCase.settings()` and `django.test.override_settings()` when being used as a context manager. Is there any difference in functionality or preference in which one to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, `settings()` and `override_settings()` can effectively used as context but, the documentation says `settings()` has to be used as context, and `override_settings()` has to be used as decorator.

But, it is quite possible that in the future, the decorator can only be used as a decorator. It is best to follow the documentation and not attempt to misuse the tools provided by Django. Django developers may have made this change to allow a transition from previous usage and the behavior is the same only for a few versions.